# Accessing a machine in a different subnet with a persistent route

Tags: windows, routing, subnet

the IP address of a windows computer is `172.16.56.109` with the subnet of `255.255.240.0` which is set by a DHCP server. On the other hand, I want to access to another computer with IP `172.20.54.10` and subnet `255.255.255.0`.

For that purpose, I added a route command to the first machine to be able to access the second machine. The route table shows that it is ok. But I can not ping the second machine while it is fully working.

```
C:\Users\mh> route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 18...........................INTERNET
 11...38 60 77 05 6c 8b ......Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
 1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.16.48.1    172.16.56.109   4235
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link       10.10.1.232     11
  10.10.1.232  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.1.232    266
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
 127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
  172.16.48.0    255.255.240.0         On-link     172.16.56.109   4491
172.16.56.109  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.16.56.109   4491
172.16.63.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.16.56.109   4491
192.168.200.1  255.255.255.255      172.16.48.1    172.16.56.109   4236
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     172.16.56.109   4492
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.10.1.232     11
 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4531
 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.16.56.109   4491
 255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.1.232    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
 Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
    172.20.54.0    255.255.255.0          1.1.1.1       1
===========================================================================
```

See the persistent routes. However, the ping fails

```
C:\Users\mh> ping 172.20.54.10

Pinging 172.20.54.10 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 172.20.54.10:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

What is the problem then and how can I fix that?

Comment: The routing must be configured on both machines.

Comment: That is a linux machine. What should I write there?

Comment: `The route table shows that it is ok. But I can not ping the second machine while it is fully working.` - The route exists but it is definitely **not** OK. Where did you get that gateway address from?

Comment: @joeqwerty: from the admin.

Comment: OK, even if 1.1.1.1 were correct (which it most certainly isn't), it wouldn't work. A host can't use a gateway to get to another network when said gateway isn't on the same network as said host. How is the host in question supposed to get to the gateway address in order to get to the desired destination address when the gateway itself is on another network?

Comment: Fore the first machine, `ipconfig /all` shows that the gateway is `172.16.48.1` and the output of `ifconfig` for the second machine shows that the gateway is `default via 172.20.54.1 dev eth1`.

Answer (score -2):

First of all: The other computer needs to know how to reach you, in order to answer the ping. The reply won't find it's way automatically.

Comment: The answer is right, but incomplete. Can you provide some details how to setup the other machine?